# Communities SAML JIT Error 18 - Invalid Account

Tags: saml

What could be the cause of error `18 - Invalid Account` `INVALID_ACCOUNT_ID` as documented in [Single Sign-On Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_jit_errors.htm)?

Two use cases in our environment:

1. User doesn't exist, Contact doesn't exist
2. User doesn't exist, Contact does exist

SAML assertion where error occurred:

```
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="User.Username" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.Username">
        <AttributeValue>foo@bar.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="User.FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.FirstName">
        <AttributeValue>Fred</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="User.LastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.LastName">
        <AttributeValue>Foo</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="User.Email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.Email">
        <AttributeValue>foo@bar.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="User.ProfileID" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="User.ProfileID">
        <AttributeValue>00e15000001J5Za</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Contact.Email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Contact.Email">
        <AttributeValue>foo@bar.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Contact.FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Contact.FirstName">
        <AttributeValue>Fred</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Contact.LastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Contact.LastName">
        <AttributeValue>Foo</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Account.AccountNumber" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.AccountNumber">
        <AttributeValue>1496</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Account.Name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.Name">
        <AttributeValue>Acme Corp.</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Account.Owner" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Account.Owner">
        <AttributeValue>00515000007D9TH</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP SAML assertion is for Use Case 2 - **User doesn't exist, Contact does exist**

The fundamental cause of the error is that the assertion contains values for an Account (specifically `Account.AccountNumber=1496`) that does not agree with the existing `AccountNumber` for the existing Contact `foo@bar.com` (whose parent `Account.AccountNumber` is null).

But more broadly, the real problem was using a one-size fits-all SAML assertion for both use cases (Contact doesn't already exist, Contact does exist).

Now, the documentation available to understand the JIT process is IMHO, somewhat contradictory.

The [official JIT for Communities documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_jit_community_requirements.htm&language=en_US&type=0) states the matching rules looking for Contacts looks for matches under any supplied `Account.AccountNumber`.

However, the [Knowledge Article on JIT Provisioning (SSO)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181155&type=1&language=en_US) states that Contacts are looked up based on email without considering their Account parent

**What we ended up doing** *(and there's probably a better way)*

- Our IdP queries SFDC to see if a Contact already exists for a given email.
- If YES, then the SAML assertion omits all `Account.XXXX` attributes.
- If NO, then the SAML assertion also omits all `Account.XXXX` attributes and uses a configurable value for `Contact.Account` pointing at a generic, Community Account for newly-provisioned contacts/users. Out-of-band processes deal with moving these Contacts to existing Accounts (or creating new Accounts)

**UPDATE**
An alternative would be to use an [Apex SAML JIT Handler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_Auth_SamlJitHandler.htm?search_text=saml) and apply your own logic to the values contained in the assertion (that is, bypass the SFDC matching rules and use your own)